# Google compute engine cannot access with external IP over nat proxy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I cannot access HTTP server by using External IP (Ephemeral) over NAT Proxy server.

I can access by using Internal IP without NAT proxy Firewall tag (`tag`)

`X.Y.Z.Q` is filtered External IP.

nmap,

```sh
$ nmap -p 80 X.Y.Z.Q
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-02-04 17:30 +03
Nmap scan report for A.B.C.D.bc.googleusercontent.com (X.Y.Z.Q)
Host is up (0.0034s latency).

PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.13 seconds
```

Telnet,

```sh
$ telnet X.Y.Z.Q 80
Trying X.Y.Z.Q...
Connected to X.Y.Z.Q.bc.googleusercontent.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Curl,

```sh
$ time curl -XGET http://X.Y.Z.Q:80
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
curl -XGET http://X.Y.Z.Q:80  0.01s user 0.01s system 0% cpu 14.981 total
```

I can access if I delete the NAT proxy tag which is `tag`.

Could you please help me to solve the problem?

Comment: Cloud NAT implements outbound NAT in conjunction with a default route to allow your instances to reach the Internet. It does not implement inbound NAT. Hosts outside of your VPC network can only respond to established connections initiated by your instances; they cannot initiate their own, new connections to your instances via NAT.

Answer (score 0):

Since  the request is an inbound for your GCP project. I assume that you are using a VM as a NAT gateway, right?

Looks like there are firewall rules pending. Please follow   [this link](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations#natgateway) .